# how to add a user to group , If user and group both have same name in linux?

Tags: linux

Here I have user and group with same name, while adding user(mqm) to the group(mqm) I am getting following problem. please give me solution.

```
 [root@localhost /]# useradd -G mqm mqm

    useradd: user 'mqm' already exist
```

Comment: Not only is this off-topic for SO, your issue is that you're trying add a user to your system that already exists (kinda like the error is telling you). That's not how you add a user to a group.

Comment: Yes this question is more appropriate for http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

`useradd` does not add a user to a group.  It adds an user account to the system.  You want to use `usermod`.  See `man usermod`

Answer (score 0):

How about `groupadd`?

```
root# groupadd -g GID mqm
```

Afterwards add user `mqm` to the group `mqm`.

See [this](http://linux.die.net/man/8/groupadd) here.